# All Users Visible to External Users in myapps.microsoft.com Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an Azure Active Directory Enterprise Application which we have invited users to use. We can invite any email address and they can sign up, then they can go to myapps.microsoft.com and see the app, this is all working great.

However, one problem is on the right side of the myapps.microsoft.com (aka https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications) on the right hand side there's a group icon:

[image]

I click on this groups icon and then All Users, I can see every single user inside our instance of Azure AD, how can I prevent this?

Comment: You can enable *Guest user permissions are limited* from portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> User settings -> External collaboration settings. This should prevent guests from seeing other users. If this is not enabled, guests can see a full user list at e.g. portal.azure.com.

Comment: Thank you juunas, you should make this an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable *Guest user permissions are limited* from portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> User settings -> External collaboration settings. This should prevent guests from seeing other users. If this is not enabled, guests can see a full user list at e.g. portal.azure.com.

Comment: We actually already have this enabled. I wonder if this could be enabled somewhere else, like perhaps at the Enterprise Application level (or maybe even group level) ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of another button, except for the user/group assignment on enterprise apps. But if you have it enabled and guests can still see the list over there, it's something that needs to be reported to the AAD product team.

Comment: I'll continue to investigate, regardless, thanks for your response.